# Storing an integer into a char* in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, char, ncurses

I'm writing some code that returns an integer, which then needs to be outputted using printw from the ncurses library. However, since printw only takes char*, I can't figure out how to output it.

Essentially, is there a way to store a integer into a char array, or output an integer using printw?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printw()` accepts `const char *` as a format specifier. What you want is

```
printw("%d",yournumber);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what exactly is "%d"?

Comment: You might want to look up the printf manpage - http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf to learn the full power of formatting. in particular %d means signed integer as the first parameter after format string here. But that's not even the top of the iceberg ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) function converts an int to char*.

Answer (score 0):

Use itoa() or sprintf() to convert integer to ascii string.

Example:

```
char s[50];
sprintf(s, "%d", someInteger);
```

now u can pass s as char*

Comment: Sorry, my answer is crap. Use Michael's.
I just wasn't sure what ncurses printw does, so I wrote a workaround.

Comment: You can delete answer. Several "bad" points: `itoa` -- there is no such thing in standard C (only `atoi`), it is better to use `snprintf(s,sizeof(s),"%d",someInteger)` -- safer.

Answer (score 0):

[itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) will help you.